# How do I iterate through all attributes (css, attr) of an element in AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

In AngularJS, I am working with a DIV tag, call it "MyPanel". If I pass the tag to the console, I can see the available functions for the DIV:

```
var panel = $("#MyPanel");
console.log(panel);
```

Which shows this in the console (snipped):

```
[object Object]
[functions]
attr
css
```

Now, this give me a length of 2:

```
console.log(panel.css.length)
```

But when I use a forEach, I get no results either way:

```
angular.forEach(panel.css, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key);
});
angular.forEach(panel.css, function(css) {
  console.log(css);
});
```

A for loop gives me unidentified for each instance.

```
for (var i = 0; i < panel.css.length; i++) {
  console.log(css[i]);
});
```

Every example I have found online requires that I KNOW the name of the attribute, for example, console.log(panel.css["background-color"]) gives me the background color. So how do I identify what these two css attributes are if I don't know their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getComputedStyle().](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
var element = document.getElementById('MyPanel'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
```

Comment: That works! Funny thing is, I was already using jQuery to get the panel: $("#MyPanel"), it threw an error when I tried your method against that object. But getting it from the document as you show above, works perfectly!